# How do I completely uninstall and reinstall a Linux kernel update?

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg, initrd

This problem started when I was installing Ubuntu updates today, 125 packages were to be updated.  I ran `sudo apt update` followed by `apt list --upgradable` and `sudo apt upgrade` on my laptop, then turned to my desktop machine to continue with other work.  I noticed the laptop's screen had gone dark, and when I looked, there was a cursor blinking in the upper left corner, nothing else on the screen.  I tried switching to a different virtual terminal, but didn't get any response.  I hit the power button briefly to see if that would get any response, and the laptop shut down.  When I restarted the laptop, it returned to the same blinking cursor screen.  This time, however, I was able to get a virtual terminal opened by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-F1` and I logged in.  I reviewed the list of packages that had been installed with a tech support guy, and he identified the problem as being a bad video driver upgrade, from `nvidia-driver-460` to `nvidia-driver-470`, and said we had to install `nvidia-driver-495`.

When I tried to install the `nvidia-driver-495` package, I got an error message saying `dpkg` had been interrupted and I needed to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which looked like it installed everything else that had been pending from the list of 125 packages.  I then tried installing `nvidia-driver-495` again, but that said it was missing `nvidia-driver-510` as a dependency.  I then ran `sudo apt install` to install `nvidia-driver-510` and all of *its* dependencies.  I checked the GUI terminal at `Ctrl-Alt-F7` and it still just had the blinking cursor.  I then ran `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495` which didn't produce any errors - but I still only had the blinking cursor on the GUI terminal.

I rebooted the laptop, and got

```
error: can't find command `hwmatch'
error: can't allocate initrd.

Press any key to continue...
```

followed by a kernel panic.  I restarted the laptop and got only the `can't allocate initrd` message, again followed by a kernel panic.  When I again restarted the laptop, I was offered the GRUB menu, and was able to boot the machine using the previous kernel, `5.13.0-28`.

After some research, I ran `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.13.0-30-generic` and rebooted the machine - and had the same failure pattern, finally booting back into the `-28` kernel to continue.  I poked around a bit more, then ran `update-grub`, rebooted - and went through the same cycle again.

I tried deleting the `-30` kernel files from `/boot`, running `sudo apt update` which said all of the packages were up to date, running `sudo apt remove` to delete all of the `-30` files, running `update-grub` again - and `apt update` kept insisting all of the packages were up to date:  It's like it knew it installed a new kernel version, but then failed to notice when it got removed.  I rebooted the laptop, which was successful since it was starting the previously working `-28` kernel - and `apt update` still didn't have a clue about the kernel upgrade.  I ran `sudo apt-get remove --purge` with the list of `-30` files, which only purged the configuration files, since the packages themselves had already been removed - and `apt update` remained blissfully ignorant of the new kernel.

I ran `apt list --installed | grep linux-image` which listed the two kernels still installed, `-27` and `-28`.  I ran `apt-cache search linux-image|grep 13|grep generic` which gave me a short list of kernels that *could* be installed.  I then ran `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30 linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic` to reinstall all of the required packages.  Part of the output was

```
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-30-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
```

which left me wondering if a required step had been passed by.  Everything else looked OK, so I rebooted the machine - and got back to

```
error: can't find command `hwmatch'
error: can't allocate initrd.
```

and the kernel panics.  I was eventually able to sort out the missing `hwmatch` problem through another couple of reboots by following advice from https://www.linux.org/threads/error-cant-find-command-hwmatch-during-boot.32618/ - copying `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/hwmatch.mod` into the `/boot/efi/efi/grub` directory I had to create.

One of the things I've noticed is the `-30` `initrd` image is 50+% larger than the others:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  99M Mar  2 16:41 initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  99M Mar  2 16:57 initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 156M Mar  2 21:41 initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
```

That may be part of the problem, or it may be a consequence of the problem, I'm not sure.

After running `sudo apt-get remove --purge` to remove all of the `-30` packages again, I ran `sudo find / -xdev -name "*5.13.0-30*"` which only returned

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

I didn't think those files were the problem, but after unsuccessfully trying to find another reason for the "Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel" message, I used `find` to delete them.  When I ran `sudo apt-get install` again, however, I got the same "Kernel preparation unnecessary" message - and rebooting got me back to the `error: can't allocate initrd` problem.

I've now removed the `-30` kernel again so I don't have to fight with the laptop when I want to reboot it, but I *would* like to install the new kernel which I'm sure has some security fixes.

What do I need to do to make Ubuntu forget that the `-30` kernel was ever installed, so that I can successfully install it into a bootable state?